# Recover deleted custom fields from managed package

Tags: managed-package, formula, custom-button, formula-field, custom-field

I had given 2 formula fields on a opportunity to display Accounts billing & shipping address. I've got the access to delete the custom fields from Salesforce team.

Due to some requirement, I've deleted these 2 formula fields from Opportunity & created managed package of major release from my developer environment including these changes.

I've another environment where I've installed previous version of this managed package which has these formula fields. But when I upgrade latest managed package (which doesn't have formula fields), I still can see formula fields on Opportunity. Though if I uninstall previous managed package & install latest one, these fields are getting deleted from Opportunity.

So is there any way these formula fields will also get automatically deleted when I upgrade managed package?

If this is not possible is there any way I can recover these custom formula fields from Opportunity in my developer environment where I create managed package? As I'm not able to get any option where I can see deleted custom fields.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. You've deleted fields in your managed package.  Once a field has been deleted, that API name cannot be used again. I'm not aware of a way you can undelete it, which is why you receive a warning stating "This action can't be undone. Any changes are permanent."
   I assume this is because subscriber orgs may still use that field, so what would happen if you deployed a new version of your managed package?  Would the subscriber org get updated?  What would happen to the data in that field?
2. You cannot force the deletion of fields in a subscriber org.  What happens if someone in the subscriber org has created a configuration (such as report or workflow) that relies on that field?

Both of these measures are to protect you, and I don't think there's any way around it.

Comment: Hi Nick, 

Thanks for your reply. It is really helpful.

To answer your questions, I was able to upgrade package at subscriber org. I had created 4 new custom fields in this managed package which got added at subscriber org after upgrading package but deleted formula fields were also available which I had deleted from managed package. Also as these are formula fields to show Accounts address on Opportunity page.

Due to this I wanted to undelete formula fields in my developer account, so atleast I can rename title of these fields so subscriber should not use those.